# Setting Up Remote Docker Daemon on Linux for Development on Macbook

Tags: linux, docker, macos

I'm facing a bit of a challenge here and could use some guidance. Here's my situation: Due to performance issues on my Macbook M1, I'm unable to use Docker effectively for my current project. So, I've shifted my development to the Linux machine, but I'd really prefer to code on my Macbook.

Here's what I'm aiming for: I want to establish a remote Docker daemon on my Linux laptop that I can access and work with from my Macbook. This way, I can write code on my Macbook while utilizing the Docker capabilities of my Linux machine.

I've done some research, and it seems like this should be possible, but I'm not quite sure where to start.

What configurations do I need to make to ensure it's secure and accessible from remote machines and connect to the remote deamon from my macbook?

I'm relatively new to working with Docker, especially in this kind of distributed setup, so any detailed steps or explanations would be greatly appreciated. If anyone has experience with a similar setup or can point me to some relevant resources, I'd be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Ubuntu machine and a mac, managed to set it up with following steps :

```
a) On Ubuntu
   1) sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service
      Replace [ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd] line with :
      ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"
   2) Exit vim and run 
      sudo systemctl daemon-reload
      sudo systemctl restart docker.service

b) On MacOS
   1) In one Terminal, run following to setup portforwarding:
      ssh -L 2375:0.0.0.0:2375 ubuntu "echo 2375:0.0.0.0:2375; sleep inf"
   2) In another Terminal, run
      export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375
      docker ps -a
```

The communication between Ubuntu and Mac is thru Secure Shell.

With a little more care, there should be no security/performance issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am going to try it. Is this a temporary solution? So is it changing at every startup to the normal settings? I am a bit afraid of changing something and i mess up my settings for linux. So i even cant access the docker on my linux dev environment.

Comment: It's not a temporary solution, can be permanent when properly tested. Anyway it's easy to roll back, just to restore the original conf file and unset DOCKER_HOST.